# Search any alphabet in string using Sql Query

Tags: sql-server

Can we search the alphabet in a string like this 'A + 2 + B' or '3 * B' or '4 / A - C'?

Basically the string is not fix, but i need a query to do this. Such as if the string has 'B' then the query will return me that i have 'B'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah, absolutely. Just like wewesthemenace mentioned, you would use `LIKE` and wildcards for comparison. Let's say your data looked something like this

```
 id  formula
 1   A + 2 + B + 5 * 3
 2   3 * B
 3   4/A - C
 4   Where is the ball
```

Let's look at the query and results

```
select * from tablename
where formula like '%B%'

result:
 1   A + 2 + B + 5 * 3
 2   3 * B
 4   Where is the ball

select * from tablename
where formula like '%B%5'

result:
 1   A + 2 + B + 5 * 3
```